# Oracle bug when adding not nullable columns with default

Tags: oracle

I have experienced this bug in the past in various instances of Oracle 11g. Don't really have access personally to Oracle support as to know if it's an identified/resolved issue.

The bug causes a query to always return the default value of a column even when the record actually has a different value.

It manifests only in specific queries and it's caused by adding a not-nullable column with a default value in a previously existing table by using one single add sentence.

Please see below for a complete reproduction.

```sql
DROP TABLE testBugMain;
DROP TABLE testBugAdditional;

-- Create two tables related to one another through real or apparent FK.
CREATE TABLE testBugMain (
    mainid NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    str VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_testBugMain PRIMARY KEY (mainid)
);
CREATE TABLE testBugAdditional (
    additionalid NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    mainid NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_testBugAdditional PRIMARY KEY (additionalid)
);

-- Insert a couple of values on both.
INSERT INTO testBugMain (mainid, str) VALUES (1, 'test-with-1');
INSERT INTO testBugMain (mainid, str) VALUES (2, 'test-with-2');
INSERT INTO testBugMain (mainid, str) VALUES (3, 'test-with-3');

INSERT INTO testBugAdditional (additionalid, mainid) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO testBugAdditional (additionalid, mainid) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO testBugAdditional (additionalid, mainid) VALUES (3, 3);

-- Required for bug to manifest: add a new column, NOT NULL, with DEFAULT value (5 in this case).
-- It needs to be added through an ALTER and both DEFAULT and NOT NULL in the same sentence for the bug to manifest.
ALTER TABLE testBugAdditional ADD bug NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 5 NOT NULL;

-- Update the value on the column, so the query below should return these values instead of 5's.
UPDATE testBugAdditional SET bug = 1 WHERE mainid = 1;
UPDATE testBugAdditional SET bug = 2 WHERE mainid = 2;
UPDATE testBugAdditional SET bug = 3 WHERE mainid = 3;

-- Sanity check (returned values are correct).
SELECT ma.mainid, ma.str, ad.bug FROM testBugMain ma INNER JOIN testBugAdditional ad ON ma.mainid = ad.mainid;

-- Insanity check (returned values are default values).
SELECT mainid, str, bug FROM
(
   SELECT ma.mainid, ma.str, ad.bug FROM testBugMain ma
   LEFT JOIN -- Required for bug to manifest (left join).
   testBugAdditional ad ON ma.mainid = ad.mainid
   ORDER BY ma.mainid ASC -- Required for bug to manifest (any order by, perhaps?).
)
WHERE rownum < 6 -- Required for bug to manifest (pagination);​
```

Although the query exposing the bug seems somewhat convoluted, I suppose is not actually that strange to have a sorted, paginated query with left joins (and, all things considered, having the bug manifest rarely is probably worse).

**Questions**

Is this an identified/resolved issue by Oracle?

Are there any workarounds for the issue?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Do you have the bug number? If so, I can find if the fix has been back ported.

Comment: Good point, I kind of assumed the questions were implicit, but now have added them directly to the details. Part of that (the workaround bit) I answered on my own to get the knowledge out there.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution/Workaround**

To get around this issue, always add not-nullable columns to existing tables in a way similar to the following:

```sql
-- Add the column as nullable with a default.
ALTER TABLE existingTable ADD newColumn NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 5;
-- Add the not-null constraint.
ALTER TABLE existingTable MODIFY newColumn NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not reproduce in 12.1 Here is my output from your test case

```
    MAINID STR                         BUG
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 test-with-1                   1
         2 test-with-2                   2
         3 test-with-3                   3


    MAINID STR                         BUG
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 test-with-1                   1
         2 test-with-2                   2
         3 test-with-3                   3
```

By the way, thank you for putting together an excellent test case. This is a great example of how to post.